# How do I add a list of programs currently running on java socket server?

Tags: java, serversocket, socketserver, single-threaded

I have set up a Java socket server.  I want the client to be able to input "Running Processes" which will cause the server to print all of the programs running on the server.  The server code looks like this:

```
// Java implementation of Server side
// It contains two classes : Server and ClientHandler
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.lang.management.ManagementFactory;
import java.lang.management.RuntimeMXBean;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

// Server class
public class Server
{
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
{
 // server is listening on port 5056
    ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(5056);

    // running infinite loop for getting
    // client request
    while (true)
    {
        Socket s = null;

        try
        {
            // socket object to receive incoming client requests
            s = ss.accept();

            System.out.println("A new client is connected : " + s);

            // obtaining input and out streams
            DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(s.getInputStream());
            DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());

            System.out.println("Assigning new thread for this client");

            // create a new thread object
            Thread t = new ClientHandler(s, dis, dos);

            // Invoking the start() method
            t.start();

        }
        catch (Exception e){
            s.close();
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
 }



 // ClientHandler class
 class ClientHandler extends Thread
 {
DateFormat fordate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");
DateFormat fortime = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss");
final DataInputStream dis;
final DataOutputStream dos;
final Socket s;


 // Constructor
public ClientHandler(Socket s, DataInputStream dis, DataOutputStream dos)
{
    this.s = s;
    this.dis = dis;
    this.dos = dos;
}

@Override
public void run()
{
    RuntimeMXBean runtimeMX = ManagementFactory.getRuntimeMXBean();
    String received;
    String toreturn;
    long uptime;
    int socket = 0;
    while (true)
    {
        try {

            // Ask user what he wants
            dos.writeUTF("What do you want?[Date | Time | Uptime | Memory Use | Netstat | Current 
 Users]..\n"+
                    "Type Exit to terminate connection.");

            // receive the answer from client
            received = dis.readUTF();

            if(received.equals("Exit"))
            {
                System.out.println("Client " + this.s + " sends exit...");
                System.out.println("Closing this connection.");
                this.s.close();
                System.out.println("Connection closed");
                break;
            }
 // creating Date object
            Date date = new Date();

 // write on output stream based on the
 // answer from the client
            switch (received) {

                case "Date" :
                    toreturn = fordate.format(date);
                    dos.writeUTF(toreturn);
                    break;

                case "Time" :
                    toreturn = fortime.format(date);
                    dos.writeUTF(toreturn);
                    break;

                case "Uptime" :
                    uptime = runtimeMX.getUptime();
                    dos.writeUTF(uptime + " ms");
                    break;

                case "Memory Use" :
                    long memory = Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory() - 
  Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory();
                    dos.writeUTF(memory + " bytes");
                    break;

                case "Netstat" :
                    s.getInputStream();
                    dos.writeUTF( s+ " bytes");
                    break;

                case "Current Users" :
                    s.getInputStream();
                    dos.writeUTF( s+ " bytes");
                    break;

                default:
                    dos.writeUTF("Invalid input");
                    break;
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    try
    {
  // closing resources
        this.dis.close();
        this.dos.close();

    }catch(IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

I am looking to add a case file that is called "Running Processes". and if the user inputs "Running Processes", they will be shown the programs currently running on the server.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a system call for implementing that, which I would suggest to avoid as much as possible in your code, due to a negative impact on the code portability:

```
           Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("<command calling task manager to list processes (OS-specific)>");

           InputStream is = proc.getInputStream();
           InputStreamReader isreader= new InputStreamReader(is);
           BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isreader);
           String line = null;
           while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)
           {
               System.out.println(line);
               //parse the line according to your needs 
           }
```

Answer (score 0):

see this stack overflow thread :

[How to get input from server console in a client server program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35374599/how-to-get-input-from-server-console-in-a-client-server-program)

as far as I am concerned: I was doing the following:

when you run your socket server program, a console is open.
read input in your main loop like a classic java console program.
but the read action will blocks the main loop !
the solution is
 1) first put your main while(true) { ... accept connection... } in a thread A 
 2) in the main part
     launch this thread A and build a new while() {} 

don't forget

```
import java.io.BufferedReader; 
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
```

```
launch thread A

BufferedReader reader =   new BufferedReader(new 

InputStreamReader(System.in)); 

while (true) {

    String command = reader.readLine(); 
    if (command.compareTo("listprg")) {
       output programs list into the console
    }
}
```